# screen = getscreen() error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The other day I decided to make a quite simple game - "Cookie Clicker". It was going fine until I stumbled upon a getscreen error. Maybe you guys know the solution to the problem?

Traceback:

```
NameError: name 'getscreen' is not defined on line 41
```

Part of code in which I suspect the problem is hiding:

```
def clicking():
if distance( cookie.pos() ) < 2:
COOKIE_COUNT = COOKIE_COUNT + 1

screen = getscreen()
screen.onclick( clicking )
```

The whole code:

```
import time
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
image_COOKIEC = "COOKIEC.png"
image_COOKIEUN = "COOKIEUN.png"
image_UPGRADEBG = "UPGRADEBG.png"

cookie = turtle.Turtle()
COOKIE_COUNT = 0
COOKIE_COUNT1 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade1 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade2 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade3 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade4 = turtle.Turtle()
upgrade5 = turtle.Turtle()

screen.addshape(image_COOKIEUN)
cookie.penup()
cookie.shape(image_COOKIEUN)
cookie.speed(0)
cookie.goto(0, 0)

COOKIE_COUNT1.speed(0)
COOKIE_COUNT1.penup()
COOKIE_COUNT1.hideturtle()
COOKIE_COUNT1.goto(-40, 170)
COOKIE_COUNT1.write("Cookies: %d" % COOKIE_COUNT, font=(None, 14, "bold"))

upgrade.speed(0)
upgrade.penup()
upgrade.hideturtle()
upgrade.goto(110, -190)
upgrade.write("Upgrades", font=(None, 12, "bold"))

def clicking():
  if distance( cookie.pos() ) < 2:
    COOKIE_COUNT = COOKIE_COUNT + 1

screen = getscreen()
screen.onclick( clicking )
```

Comment: `turtle.getscreen()` instead of `getscreen()`?

Comment: I always used `getscreen ()` and it worked fine until now.

Comment: That is because you always used `from turtle import *` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either do:

```
screen = turtle.getscreen()
```

or

```
from turtle import getscreen
screen = getscreen()
```

Personally, I recommend the first approach since it shows where `getscreen` comes from.

Comment: Oh and one more thing. Now, when I try and click the cookie I get the error `TypeError: clicking() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given) at <unknown>`. I didn't change the code.

Comment: That is a separate issue, please post a different question and you will get help. I suggest to go back and read the documentation for [screen.onclick()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick) before you do.

Comment: Thanks. I most certainly will.